# How can I get my Perl one-liner to show only the first regex match in the file?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with this format:

```
KEY1="VALUE1"
KEY2="VALUE2"
KEY1="VALUE2"
```

I need a perl command to only get first occurrence of `KEY1`, ie `VALUE1`.

I'm using this command:

`perl -ne 'print "$1" if /KEY1="(.*?)"/' myfile`

But the result is:

`VALUE1VALUE2`

`EDIT`

The solution must be with perl command, because the system there is no other regex tool.

Comment: You say "there is no other regex tool".  Do you have `grep`?

Comment: Yes, but withou `-P` option. Is an old system with debian 4.

Comment: Your grep should still have regexes. They just won't be Perl regexes.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for the edits. Could you answer how to apply regex for this case using only `grep` without `-P`?

Comment: You have regexes with out -P.  They're just more tricky.  For instance you could do this to find your match and then chip away at the results until you get just what you want: `grep 'KEY1' foo.txt  | head -n 1 | grep '"[^"]*' -o | head -n 1 | grep '[^"]*' -o`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `and last` to your one-liner like so (extra quotes removed):

```
perl -ne 'print $1 and last if /KEY1="(.*?)"/' myfile
```

This works because [`-n` switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-n) effectively wraps your code in a `while` loop. Thus, if the pattern matches, `print` is executed, which succeeds and thus causes `last` to be executed. This exits the `while` loop.

You can also use the more verbose `last LINE`, which specifies the (implicit) label of the `while` loop that iterates over the input lines. This last form is useful for more complex code than you have here, such as the code involving nested loops.

Answer (score 3):

You can exit after printing first match:

```sh
perl -ne '/KEY1="([^"]*)"/ && print ($1 . "\n") && exit' file

VALUE1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed -nE 's/^KEY1="(.*)"/\1/p;q' file
```

The `p;q` means 'print' then 'quit'

Comment: You answer should be `sed -nE 's/^KEY1="(.*)"/\1/p;q' file` otherwise the `"` would be returned. Thanks for answering.

Comment: `sed` regexes are bugged. The Perl ones are the best. I was using a sed regex once, and for hours it badly matched my input. When I tried Perl, it worked awesomely.

Answer (score 2):

For registration only, thanks to [@Andy Lester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester)'s comment I also found a simple way to solve the problem with `grep` and `cut`, without the need for regex:

`grep -a -m1 'KEY1' file | cut -d "\"" -f2`

return

`VALUE1`

Comment: You probably also have awk on the box.